# How would this system behave?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Of course I know (and firmly believe) that perpetuum mobiles are impossible, but I'm still puzzled about why this particular system would not be in movement forever:

[image: Perpetuum mobile?!]

So, to make it clear: I assume that there is a fixed negatively charged ball below, and another negatively charged ball hangs from above via a rod, which is attached to the ceiling via a freely moving joint. It is assumed to be on Earth, so gravity has it's usual effects.

EDIT: I imagine this system is in 3D.

For me it seems that this system simply does not have a stable point, and thus, it should be in movement forever. I am clearly wrong, but what do I miss?

Comment: You seem to think the hanging ball would oscillate. Why? The repelling force points directly upwards.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Yes, but if I pull the ball to the side? Then it is not pointing upward.

Comment: @CountTo10: I'm afraid I can't do that :( I'm not educated enough.

Comment: I can only agree with ACuriousMind, have you actually tried it? (no offence, but it seems easy to do, there could well be a youtube video.)

Comment: Then, after swinging a bit, it might eventually stay at one side, with the string slightly angled w.r.t. your rest position. I still don't see where the perpetual motion is supposed to be.

Comment: @CountTo10: Nope, but I plan to! :) But the idea just came to my mind a minute ago.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: But in 3D?

Comment: I also don't see how the dimension is supposed to play a role. Please edit your question to explain *why* you think there should be perpetual motion here.

Comment: It is included why I think so. So I don't see what more should I include. Look, I know it is a bit of a stupid question, but I am puzzled by it, and I think it's fair to ask then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of friction and drag, your 3D contraption **would move forever** given some initial velocity in the same way that a thrown ball would move forever if not acted on by external forces.  You mention that it "does not have a stable point", but neither does a ball floating in space.

It would never move forever in the real world because there would always be at least a little bit of friction.

Even with no friction, it would not be a **perpetual motion machine** ([a hypothetical machine that can do work indefinitely without an energy source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion)) because it is doing no work.

Comment: Thank you, your answer clearly points to something I didn't fully understood up to now: that a perpetuum mobile is not something that moves forever (as the name would imply...) but something that does work forever without energy input.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing that the system must have two stable equilibria, one on each side, even though you have made the central equilibrium unstable.  Or, thinking in 3D, the stable equilibrium is a circle, which is only marginally stable around its circumference, but marginal stability is not instability.

Comment: Yup, I meant it to be in 3D. So it has a marginally stable region in the form of a circle, I see. But how would that look like in reality? How would it behave in the long term?

Comment: +1 Sorry Ken, I only read your answer now. Benjamin, in the long term, stable is stable, unless there is a change in the set up, such as adding charge or giving it a push.

Comment: @CountTo10: So, it would settle on some arbitrary point of the circular stability region, and that's it?

Comment: Prove me wrong, and I'll buy you a (virtual) beer :)  Put a picture on your post with your own answer.  It's not much different from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45SoeCrf4dQ

Comment: @Benjamin: In real life, some imperfection would break the rotational symmetry.  Perhaps the pivot would not be exactly "above"(defined by the local gravity vector, including everything even fictitious forces and gravity from the Sun, etc.) the bottom charge, or tidal effects around the circle owing to the Moon 's gravity or tidal effects in the fictitious forces would tug on it asymmetrically.  This would pick out a point along the circle that has the lowest gravitational potential, and the motion would eventually settle there.